# Accessing socket.io when redirecting an Apache subdirectory to Node.js

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io

I am wanting to redirect an Apache subdirectory to a Node.js app. I have added the following in my Apache VirtualHost .conf file for my regular domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Already existing Apache lines here removed to keep this post short

    # The following are all the new lines I have added

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    <Location /mysubdir>
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, now when trying to connect to my site through `http://example.com/subdirname` I get a 404 error for `socket.io`.

In my app.js I had the following:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Based on another stackoverflow post I changed my app.js to this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server, {path: '/mysubdir/socket.io'}).listen(server);
```

But it still gives me a 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I posted an answer below that seems to be working for me. I've only tested it now for a few minutes, so feel free to look it over in case you notice anything that will cause me issues down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that I did not need to make any changes to my app.js only to my html code. So to solve, I restored my app.js to:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

And modified the following lines in my html code:

I changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mysubdir/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I also changed:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

To:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:3000');
```

Everything now seems to be working the way it should. It is interesting, however, that all I needed to change was the client side. Most of the other examples I found either required changing the server side app or adding redirects to the Apache hosts file. Neither of those worked for me. Perhaps there is something I am missing?